# Flip first name and last name to last name first name

Tags: javascript, string, split, reverse, swap

I'm trying to swap the first names and last names of from textarea

**Input:**
John Doe

Jane Doe

Joe Doe

Joan Doe

Jenny van Doe

**Desired output:**
Doe, John

Doe, Jane

Doe, Joe

Doe, Joan

van Doe, Jenny

**But getting:**
Doe Jane Doe Joe Doe Joan Doe Jenny van Doe, John

The logic is pretty simple, take the first string as first name and the rest as last name, if there are middename it will also be taken in as last name separated by a comma.

It is working with this code but only for a one liner. Hence if it's a list names from a textarea
it will take first string as first name and assign the rest of the names to last name.

```js
var splitName = document.getElementById("splitName");
splitName.onclick = function() {

  var fullname = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
  console.log(fullname);

  var spaceIndex = fullname.indexOf(" ");
  var firstname;
  var lastname;

  if (spaceIndex == -1) {
    lastname = fullname;
    lastname = "";
  } else {

    var firstname = fullname.substring(0, spaceIndex);
    var lastname = fullname.substr(spaceIndex + 1);
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = lastname + ", " + firstname;


};
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="fullName"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="splitName" class="hwbutton">Reverse</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` to separate the lines and then use a loop.

```js
var splitName = document.getElementById("splitName");
splitName.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';
  const value = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
  value.split('\n').forEach(fullname => {

    var spaceIndex = fullname.indexOf(" ");
    var firstname;
    var lastname;

    if (spaceIndex == -1) {
      lastname = fullname;
      lastname = "";
    } else {
      firstname = fullname.substring(0, spaceIndex);
      lastname = fullname.substr(spaceIndex + 1);
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += lastname + ", " + firstname + "<br>";
  });
};
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="fullName">Jane Doe
Joe Doe
Joan Doe
Jenny van Doe</textarea>
</div>

<div id="splitName" class="hwbutton">Reverse</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @Andy Can you please be more specific about what is not working? I think this works fine. (Do you clicked on the button?)

Comment: Run the snippet. The names are not in "lastname, firstname" format.

Comment: @Andy I don't know why you should have a different output. But I have [this](https://ibb.co/th710w4) output in the format "lastname, firstname".

Comment: My mistake. You were logging to console so I couldn't see the output. I've removed that line from your code so the snippet looks better.

Comment: Okay, yes in the small preview that was indeed confusing. Thanks for the mention and the edit! I made as few changes as possible to keep the intention of the OP. So also the logging remained in it.

Comment: That's why I upvoted your answer. It was in the spirit of the question to keeps things as simple as possible in the answer. I completely ignored that of course.

Comment: @SvenEberth Thanks a lot, will be using this.

Comment: @SvenEberth Looks good.  I just think that you might have mistakenly typed `lastname` twice in the if block.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it.

```js
const rearrangeName = (name) => {
  // convert name string into array, split by spaces
  name = name.split(' ')

  // get first name
  const firstName = name[0]

  // reconnect the rest of the name by spaces
  // trim is just to remove trailing spaces
  const restOfName = name.slice(1).join(' ').trim()

  // return rearranged name, separated by comma
  return restOfName + ', ' + firstName
}

// Above is the main function. This following is just if you want to do 
// something with the DOM.
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const output = document.querySelector('.output')

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // two \n's because that's how they're separated in textarea
  const values = textArea.value.split(/\n\n/g)
  
  // I'm just clearing out the old values if the user wants to try again.
  output.innerHTML = ''

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    output.innerHTML += rearrangeName(values[i]) + '<br>'
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea>
John Doe

Jane Doe

Joe Doe

Joan Doe

Jenny van Doe
</textarea>

<button>Print formatted name to output</button>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version

```js
const splitName = document.getElementById("splitName");
splitName.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var fullnames = document.getElementById("fullName").value.split("\n");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fullnames.map(
      name => {
        const [first, ...last] = name.trim().split(/ /);
        return `${last.join(" ")}, ${first}`
      })
    .join("<br>")
});
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="fullName">John Doe
Jane Doe
Joe Doe
Joan Doe
Jenny van Doe</textarea>
</div>

<div id="splitName" class="hwbutton">Reverse</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you need to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text on the carriage return. That way you get an array you can then iterate over. You can use a `for-loop`, but I updated your code a little using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and a simple regular expression.

```js
// Cache the elements
const splitName = document.getElementById('splitName');
const fullname =  document.getElementById('fullName');

// We have a regex that finds first name match, and
// then a match for the last name
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z ]+){1,}/;
// -------first name ^, last name --^

splitName.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {

  // So now we need some names. We grab the value, trim off
  // any spaces, and then split the names into an array
  const names = fullname.value.trim().split('\n');

  // Now, using `map` we can iterate over the array of names
  // and find matches. `match` also returns an array. The
  // first element is always the complete match, and the other
  // elements contain the matches we specified in our regex
  const result = names.map(name => {

    const match = name.match(regex);

    // So we ignore the first match, and the grab the next match
    // (first name), and then everything else (last name)
    const [ , first, ...last ] = match;

    // And then return the new string
    return `${last}, ${first}`;
  });

  console.log(result);

};
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="fullName">
John Doe
Jane Doe
Joe Doe
Joan Doe
Jenny van Doe
  </textarea>
</div>

<div id="splitName" class="hwbutton">Reverse</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)